# Plotly MATLAB fig2plotly() for Patch Object (Isosurface)

Tags: matlab, plot, plotly

I am trying to use the MATLAB Plotly API to generate a Plotly visualization for different contours I have. I have a 31x31x86x127 Matrix in MATLAB: (x,y,a,b). For a fixed b, I generated a patch isosurface object:

```
>> time1 = value(:,:,:,1);
>> [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(1:31, 1:31, 1:86);
>> p = patch(isosurface(X,Y,Z, time1, 0));
>> isonormals(X,Y,Z, time1, p)
>> p.FaceColor = 'red';
>> p.EdgeColor = 'none';
>> fig2plotly();
```

However, the Plotly figure is blank. When you toggle 'Show nearest data point', the Data points do show up though in the label!

https://plot.ly/39/~txizzle/

What's going wrong here?

Comment: have you tried `fig2plotly(gcf)` or starting your figure as `f=figure()` and then `fig2plotly(f)` ?

Comment: fig2plotly(gcf) worked! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of `fig2plotly()` is sparse, but some of the examples in their webpage might suggest that `fig2plotly(gcf)` can work.